# R code to add values in a column unique to some activities in another column

Tags: r

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way in R to make a column with values which uniquely identify an activity in another column. In the attached image I want a way to add the column "activity_instance" which uniquely differentiate the activities in the "activity" column. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `data.table::rleid(df$activity)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` :

```
df$activity_instance <- data.table::rleid(df$activity)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rle` from `base R`

```
df$activity_instance <- with(rle(df$activity), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use
rleidv(x, cols=seq_along(x), prefix=NULL)